# Given U(a,b) and V(a,b) as the real and complex part of a complex function f(z), can I find out what is f(z) before being split?

Tags: complex-analysis

I was given exercises regarding complex functions. Some of them has this form, "Given $U(a,b)$ = some polynomial, as the real part of complex function $f(a+bi)$, find a differentiable function $f(z)$"

This is a rather simple exercise using Cauchy-Riemann conditions. However, the function $f(z)$ I get is of the form $U(a,b) + iV(a,b)$. Is there a way to backtrack and find what *could* $f(z)$ possibly be? (for example, $f(z) = |z|$)

I realized that turning $f(z)$ into $U(a,b) + iV(a,b)$ is not an injective function, so this may be hopeless afterall.

Comment: Can you please provide an example that shows that turning $f(z)$ into $U(a,b)+iV(a,b)$ is not an injective function?

Comment: $|z|$ is not differentiable; the answer is unique up to an imaginary constant

Comment: @Conrad I know, it was merely an example of what I meant by $f(z)$

Comment: if you do not want to use C-R (or u want to guess etc), a way would be to express $U$ in $z=x+iy, \bar z=x-iy$ terms (so replace $x =(z+\bar z)/2$ etc) and note that the result can have only separate terms since $U$ is harmonic (in other words there is no $z^k\bar z^m, k, m \ge 1$ and then the guess is terms that get rid of $\bar z$ part constitute $V$, while the $z$ terms are forced to make it real

Comment: for example, suppose $U=x^2-y^2=\frac{z^2+\bar z^2}{2}$ then $V$ must have $-\bar z^2/(2i)$ so $U+iV$ gets rid of the pesky $\bar z^2$ term that blocks analyticity and then you can try and see what expression containing only powers of $z$ can be added to make $V$ real and you stumble upon $z^2/(2i)$ giving for $f=U+iV=z^2$; of course you can stumble upon $z^2/(2i)+15$ which gives $f(z)=z^2+15i$ but that is the only freedom you have

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos $f_1(z) = z \cdot \bar{z}$ and $f_2(z) = z^2 + \sin(arg(z))\cdot\cos(arg(z))\cdot{|z|}^2$

Comment: $f_1(z)=|z|^2=z\bar z$ is not harmonic so cannot be real part of an analytic polynomial, hence that example is incorrect

Comment: @AyamGorengPedes What is $\operatorname{arg}(z)$?

Comment: @Conrad Then perhaps it is injective. I based my assumption based on $z\cdot\bar{z}=a^2 - b^2$ doesn't feel too *unique*. However on your example with U and V, I don't think we can do that. The coefficients of $V(a,b) must be real, no?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos $\arctan(\frac{b}{a})$, the angle between $Re$-axis and the line segment from origin to (a,b) in complex plane.

Comment: The coefficients of $V$ are real if you express $V$ in $x,y$ terms but otherwise may be complex in $z, \bar z$ terms since those are complex variables and the condition on $V$ is to take real values; as noted $U$ determines $V$ uniquely up to a real constant, hence $U$ determines $f$ uniquely up to an imaginary constant